# Testcafe typeText on IOS devices does not work on third party iframe

Tags: ios, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I have some problems using typeText on IOS devices and testcafé. The same script works on desktop browsers, android browsers but not IOS. I have tried hosted real devices on Browserstack Automate and the neat testcafe function --qr-code on devices in my hand. Same behavior.
I do not get any errors in the code adding the text. I get the error when the following element is supposed to be visible.

I tried with WebDriver as well before (coded in Java), but ran into the same problem with sendKeys()

I am pretty sure IOS and Safari need some special treatment but I can not find out what is needed.

My code is like this:

```
async payWithCreditCardSecure(cardNumber, expiryDate, cvc) {
    await t
        .click(this.creditCardRadioButton)
        .switchToIframe(this.creditCardNumberIFrame)
        .typeText(this.creditCardNumber, cardNumber, {paste: true, replace: true})
        .switchToMainWindow()
        .switchToIframe(this.creditCardExpiryDateIFrame)
        .typeText(this.creditCardExpiryDate, expiryDate, {paste: true, replace: true})
        .switchToMainWindow()
        .switchToIframe(this.creditCardCVCIFrame)
        .typeText(this.creditCardCVC, cvc, {paste: true, replace: true})
        .switchToMainWindow()
        .click(this.finishPurchaseCreditCard) **// BUTTON NEVER GETS ACTIVE SINCE NO TEXT IS ADDED**
        .typeText(this.creditCardSecureUsername, creditCardCredentials.user)  **//HERE IT FAILS**
        .typeText(this.creditCardSecurePassword, creditCardCredentials.password)
        .click(this.creditCardSecureSubmit)
}
```

The element looks like this:
enter image description here

UI looks like this:
enter image description here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I created a simple project with an input in an iframe and couldn't reproduce the issue. Could you please share a public URL to your website or provide your code?

Comment: The public URL is a webshop, so you should be able to test without doing the actual purchase. https://www.ahlens.se/

Comment: Please provide us with the full code of your test so we can reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: Hi! 
Clone this repo https://github.com/norhak/norhak.git.

To run, do like this:
1. Edit SetEnv.sh you are running through Browserstack. Add user credentials.
2. $ source SetEnv.sh 
3. npm run test:browserstackiPhone

The test is cut after adding the credit card number since this is the production site.

I have also tester without browserstack with command
$ testcafe remote ./spec --qr-code
So that might be easier to reproduce if you have an IOS device at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I've reproduced the described behavior in Safari. I've created an issue in the TestCafe repository. Please thack the following thread to be notified of the progress:

[The typeText action doesn't work in third-party iframe in Safari](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4851)

**(UPDATE: the issue has been fixed)**